# OIDC token invalid when put into kubeconfig

Tags: docker, kubernetes, security, kubectl

I can connect to the Kubernetes API from a container running inside the cluster with an OIDC token like so:

```
kubectl —token $token get pod
```

I would now like to prepare a kubeconfig such that other programs that don’t support `--token` can connect as well. I am trying this in the specific context of `docker buildx create --driver kubernetes ...; docker buildx build .` where the 2nd part needs to create a `deployment`. Here's how I have proceeded:

```
tmp=$(mktemp -p $PWD)
kubectl config --kubeconfig $tmp set-cluster cluster \
  --server https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT \
  --certificate-authority /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt 
kubectl config --kubeconfig $tmp set-credentials user --auth-provider oidc \
  --auth-provider-arg idp-issuer-url=... \
  --auth-provider-arg client-id=... \
  --auth-provider-arg id-token=$token
kubectl config --kubeconfig $tmp set-context context --cluster cluster --user user
kubectl config --kubeconfig $tmp use-context context
export KUBECONFIG=$tmp
kubectl get pod
```

`kubectl get pod` now fails with "Unable to connect to the server: No valid id-token, and cannot refresh without refresh-token". Why does it deem `$token` invalid when it has worked just before with `kubectl get pod --token` (and still does)? How can create a kubeconfig "envelope" around `$token` such that `kubectl get pod` will accept it and won't fail? (I've not specified `refresh-token` because it shouldn't be needed in the case of a valid token and because I don't have it readily available inside the container.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the (preliminary) conclusion that this cannot be done.

First, I had set the wrong `idp-issuer-url`. I had selected the IDP that normally serves during OIDC authentication to the Kubernetes cluster. But `$token` (or `$CI_JOB_JWT` in GitLab CI/CD parlance) was not generated there but by GitLab instead. Inspection e.g. at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) indicates `"iss": "kubernetes/serviceaccount"`, so `--auth-provider-arg idp-issuer-url=kubernetes/serviceaccount` should be a better choice.

But this inspection also reveals that the JWT does carry a claim `aud`, hence no client-id. `kubectl` in particular (and perhaps OIDC in general) apparently insist on a non-empty client-id (otherwise: "error: Must provide client-id"). So I guess what happens is that `kubectl` checks the issuer (signer) and client-id for `$token` (claims `iss` and `aud` in its JWT payload) before it will use it. The check for client-id must fail, at which point `kubectl` tries a token refresh and that fails again.

If that diagnosis is correct this cannot be done because `kubectl` insists on a client-id whereas GitLab does not provide one in `$token`. I guess the reason for the discrepancy is that GitLab's is a general JWT token, whereas `kubectl` (more specifically, its OIDC autentication provider)  expects a OIDC id tokens in particular (unless it is invoked with `--token`, which apparently bypasses kubeconfig and hence the OIDC authentication provider).